# Why is url() needed in CSS when specifiying background-image property?

Tags: css

Some insights into the decision would be appreciated. I have a hard time finding the reasons why this is specified in the CSS design.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect they already foresaw the need to have other background images than URL-based ones. `linear-gradient` for instance.

Also, since image files do not have to have a file name extension, it would be difficult to distinguish the image file from the other properties in the `background` shorthand method

Comment: How would one add the linear-gradient type of background images, as another example?

Comment: @stanigator An example is `linear-gradient(0, green, blue)` instead of `url(filename.ext)`. However, the browsers don't support this syntax yet; you'll have to use the vendor-specific prefix for your browser. `-moz-linear-gradient` for Firefox for instance. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/linear-gradient

Answer (score 4):

First of all, [*all* URL/URI](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri) resources are notated with `url()`. Second, how do you want to differ between a standard value like `none` or `inherit` and images `none`/`inherit`?

For example you could create an image called `none`, send its MIME type correctly and then use

```
background-image: none;
```

What should be used now? The stored file? Or the value called `none`? Another example are cursor files. You could name your cursor file `pointer`:

```
cursor: pointer;
```

To avoid this ambiguity you use `url()` to denote URIs/URLs. Then it's absolutely clear what to use and you can name the graphics/resources however you want:

```
background-image: url(none);
cursor: url(pointer);
```